ARKit Face Tracking: Get accurate 3D coordinates of physical screen center
I'm working on an ARKit face tracking application using the front-facing camera. I need to get the 3D coordinates of the center of the physical screen in world space, as accurately as possible. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

Get the 3D coordinates of the center of the physical screen in world space.
Ensure these coordinates are as close to the to the actual screen center as possible, not at a fixed distance.
Be able to convert between 2D screen coordinates and 3D world coordinates accurately.

In other words, what's the best way to get accurate 3D coordinates of the physical screen center in an ARFaceTrackingConfiguration setup? And how can I reliably convert between 2D screen coordinates and 3D world coordinates in this context?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
I've tried using unprojectPoint() like this:
let plane = sceneView.pointOfView! // Camera node
let midpoint = CGPoint(x: screenSize.width / 2, y: screenSize.height / 2) // Screen midpoint

// Attempt to unproject the 2D midpoint back into the 3D world on the defined plane.
let worldPoint = camera!.unprojectPoint(midpoint, ontoPlane: planeTransform, orientation: .portrait, viewportSize: screenSize)

However, I've discovered that the plane needs to be offset by approximately 0.025 units along the camera's forward vector to achieve accurate results when converting between 2D and 3D coordinates. Without this offset, the conversion yields significant inaccuracies.
What's causing this need for an offset, and is there a more robust way to handle this conversion without relying on a manual adjustment? Are there any ARKit functions or techniques that can provide more precise results in this scenario?
Edit: Looking for 1:1 2D screen coordinates to 3D screen coordinates and vice versa.

Hi, and welcome to SO. I have a similar issue, I use ARFaceTrackingConfig in my app, to get the center of my face, to guide a node. And the face should then be centered above the center of the screen (more or less). I tuned this to adjust the offset with a static value. It seems there is no native way, to get the physical distance or offset to i.Ex to the front camera, as it varies from device to device.

I figured out a quite acceptable solution using this static values here: let yShift: Float = -1.0 / let xShift: Float = 0.4. this gives me a quite accurate offset result, on several devices, including the iPadPro 12.9 and the iPhone 15 Pro Max. Do you need more information?

Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I should have been more specific (will add an edit). I am looking for 1:1 screen coordinates in 2d to screen coordinates in 3d rather than just an offset.
